# Find a range into an sql array

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to find a matching range based on a given value x

For example, in column A, we have the value: `{15-17,18-20,21-23}`

The output expected for the `x=16` should be `15-17`
or x=21 should be `21-23`

Any idea of the best way to achieve that ?

Comment: What data type is that column?

Comment: It is a string type

Comment: i think you should make a iteration on  your string ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sql
select rangetext 
from unnest('{15-17,18-20,21-23}'::text[]) as t(rangetext)
where 16 between split_part(rangetext , '-', 1)::integer 
             and split_part(rangetext , '-', 2)::integer;
```

Comment: Top thanks, I'll try that immediately !!